# Perform a loop on filtered PivotItems only

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I want to sum the `DataRange.Value` of some `PivotItems` of a `PivotTable` that match certain criteria, and I wan't to do it every time a `PageFilter` changes. Here is my code:

```
Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pi As PivotItem, q as Double
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    q = 0
    For Each pi In pt.PivotFields(1).PivotItems
         If pi.Name = someCriteria Then
                    q = q + pi.DataRange.Value
         End If
    Next pi
End Sub
```

The code runs every time the PT changes (obviously), and runs very well until a `PageFilter` hides an item matching `someCriteria`, and then a `1004 Error` occurs, given that it can't retrive the `DataRange` property of `pi`.

Two questions:

(In this context) Is there a way to run the code only when a `PageFilter` changes (or it has to be done with a `Worksheet_Change` event)?

How do I run my `For-Loop` only whithin the filtered items?

I've figured out a solution doing some error handling, but I'm guessing there has to be a more elegant way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error.  If I create a simple pivot table with Page items "Test" and "Test2" and change the page filter to not show "test" I don't get an error 1004.  The is with someCriteria set equal to "Test."  I do get an error 13 Type Mismatch, whether "Test" hidden or not, because it's trying to add a range to q.

[image: Error 13]

The line highlighted by the debugger is "q = q + pi.DataRange.Value."

Note that the address of pi.DataRange isn't really dependent on whether Test is selected in the page filter.  For example, in the picture Test2 is selected and the pi.DataRange.Address is equal to B4:B5.

So, if I change the code to the following, it runs without error, but it results in 3, even though Test is not selected:

```
Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim pt As PivotTable, pi As PivotItem, q As Double
Dim someCriteria As String
Dim cell As Excel.Range

someCriteria = "test"
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
q = 0
For Each pi In pt.PivotFields(1).PivotItems
    If pi.Name = someCriteria Then
        For Each cell In pi.DataRange
            q = q + cell.Value
        Next cell
        Debug.Print q
    End If
Next pi
End Sub
```

Because I can't duplicate your initial success or the specific failure, I'm clearly not much help.  Perhaps with more details about the structure of your pivot table I could be.

I can say positively that if you want to capture just changes in the page filter, you need to code off the Worksheet_Change event, as you suspected.

Comment: That's clever.  I'd just do the Worksheet_Change and check if the cell changed was in the pivot table's report filter range.  You could either check for a named range, or programatically determine the report filter range.  I'd do the first, unless the pivot table might move.

Comment: Regarding the filter change, I had to capture it with a combination of `PivotTable_Update` event and a `Worksheet_Change` event, due the inability to isolate the filter from the rest of the table. Any change in the Pivot Table (not only in the filter) was triggering the macro. Regarding the `for-loop`, I don't understand why you are getting a `13` error and I never got it. On the other hand, I'm sure I've been doing a bad reference to the `PivotItems`. The actual `PivotField` is a `RowField`, and its second in hierarchy. In the actual code, I'm refering it by name, wich can be a problem.